# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert google chart into an image.

I found this code on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SCjm8/32/. I want to download the image without pressing the button. Anything i try im always getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined` error.

I tried making something like this for example (#test is id of the 'download image' button):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click();
 });
```

OR:

```
  <body onload="toImg(document.getElementById('pie_div'));">
```

But always getting the same error..
Any suggestions how can i make it so it would download the image without pressing the button? How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCjm8/35/). it should work now. you are using `script` tag inside `script` tag.

Comment: Its not working, i still need to press buttons to activate the functions. I want it to download the image on load

Comment: Thanks! It works on jfiddle but not on my localhost, i will try to make it work on my localhost now, tyvm